# Call a function inside const React/Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, recharts

In my application, I want to conditionally render something, so I made a function `getItem` which I want to call in my custom Tooltip, `const CustomTooltip`.

How can I call the function with the `return` of my custom tooltip? Currently, it render           getState("A"),
getState("B"),
getState("C"), on the tooltip. See code below:

```
  const numberStates = 3;
  function getState({payload}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>, state: string ){
    if(payload){
      for(let i = 0; i < numberStates; i++){
        if(payload[i].dataKey == state){
          return <p>{ payload[i] } : { payload[i].value }</p>
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }


  const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>) => {
    if(active && payload && payload.length){
      return (
        <div className = "custom-tooltip">
          getState("A")
          getState("B")
          getState("C")
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your calls to `getState` in brackets:

```
  const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>) => {
    if(active && payload && payload.length){
      return (
        <div className = "custom-tooltip">
          {getState("A")}
          {getState("B")}
          {getState("C")}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
```

You should expect to use this syntax if you're trying to utilize any javascript functionalities within the JSX.

More information can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) regarding functions in react. You can scroll down to the "Example: Passing params using arrow functions" section and see an example of how brackets are necessary for using a map on the state.

Comment: putting in the {} helped, but another problem is that I am unsure how to pass payload of CustomTooltip into the {getState("A")}. When I tried {getState(payload, "A")} it says: Type 'Payload<ValueType, NameType>[]' has no properties in common with type 'TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>'.

Comment: Typescript is not my friend, maybe someone else can chime in here :)